# NSFetchedResultsController Update

Tags: swift2

I have table view with 2 labels on the cell 'in label' and 'out label'. 
when you click 'button 1' the table automatically add row with fade effect with information on 'in label' = time now and 'out label' = nil . When 'out label' is nil the text in cell is = "empty".
I have 'button 2' what function I need, to update the added row by 'button 1' when 'button 2' is clicked, to update 'out label' with the time of the clicking on 'button 2' ? Because now I do it with batch update and when update is performed the 'out label' is still 'empty'

Comment: Please add some code showing what you're trying to do.